# Getting top cell path section when using custom UITableView inset

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

I'm using the following code to determine which UITableView row header is currently stuck as you're scrolling. It was working fine until I added a custom top inset on my table in order for the table's content to initially sit below one of my views:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   let paths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows()
   let topCellPath: NSIndexPath = paths?.first as NSIndexPath
   println(topCellPath.section)
}
```

The issue is that now it's not reporting a change in section header until the previously stuck header goes well out of sight/underneath the navigation bar.

How can I change the code so that it still reports the correct top cell path section/row header thats stuck even with a custom top inset on my table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this where "subNavView" is the view where my UITableView top inset begins:

```
let bounds = subNavView.bounds
let localFrame = tableView.convertRect(bounds, fromView: subNavView)
let point = CGPointMake(0, localFrame.origin.y + localFrame.size.height + 1)
let topCellPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
let topCellPathSection = topCellPath?.section
```